# while loop should be breaking but continues

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

I'm running a loop that does the task upto a point, takes a break by waiting some seconds and then continues. If I run this code I would expect the loop to break when b is set to 1 and call the wait function but somehow it does not stop. If I remove the function call after while loop, it stops as expected. What is going on here?

```
 import threading

 def wait():
    timer = threading.Timer(5,run())
    timer.start()
        
 def run():
    a = 1      
    b = 2

    while a<100 and b ==2:
            a = a +1 
            print(a)

            if a > 57:
                b = 1

    wait()
        
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: In whatever language this is; is it correct that `wait` invokes `run` and `run` invokes `wait` unconditionally?   It many languages, that is an infinite loop.

Comment: Looking at your code the expected behaviour would be: - print the values from `2` to `58`. - wait for 5 seconds. - print the values from `2` to `58`. -wait for 5 seconds. -print the values from `2`to `58` ... and so on and so forth. Do you experience a different behaviour?

Comment: sorry added python tag. yes that is intended, with a time stop, in real code a is passed through and the code stops when a gets to 100

Comment: Shouldn't it be `threading.Timer(5, run)` ?  That is, invoke run after 5s rather than immediately.

Comment: Well when I execute your code, I get nealy the intended behaviour. Ie values printed from 2 to 58 and then after a while I get an exeption about the maximum recursion depth being reached. Although it doesn't wait the five second. But `a` never reaches 100

Comment: i get the result that the loop keeps printing numbers going from 1 to 57 until max recursion depth exceeded and crashes. it does not wait 5 seconds.

Comment: mevets thank you, I added brackets incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that missing timeout too. But that has nothing to do with the while loop like your title suggests. The while loop is working correctly. I'm a python beginner too. But maby @mevets suggestion helps ...

Comment: If you just want to wait 5 seconds, why not use `time.sleep(5)` instead of the `wait()` call? Wrap all that in another `while True` loop to restart your standard loop (or, if you really want to continue after printing 58, just put a `time.sleep(5)` under the `b = 1` assignment).

Comment: Read @mevets comment again.  And understand it.  Your `threading.Timer(...)` call is incorrect.

Comment: 9769953 - the answer is sleep blocks the thread, there are a bunch of other stuff going on at the same time that I cannot block, threading.Timer does not block.

Comment: You have generated a recursive call here, not a timer reset function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it currently is written, wait function might as well be written:

```
def wait():
    run()
```

Because the run is called and runs to completion before the result
is passed to threading.Timer().  In the meantime, the run function calls
wait() again (recursion).  This repeats over an over again, never returning
just fills the stack until overflow which is what you are seeing.

Just change your wait function to:

```
def wait():
   timer = threading.Timer(5,run)
   timer.start()
```

(Removing the parentheses after run).  This passes the REFERENCE to the run function, and not the RESULTS of the run function to the Timer() call.

This will behave as you must have intended, running your run function every 5 seconds.